# Graph returned an error: This authorization code has been used?

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

This authorization code has been used error returned when refreshing the page after login using facebook id. I have read many blogs and I did not get any idea about this issue. Here is my code.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVcrt.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59SzI.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHPdZ.jpg).

```
'Providers\FacebookRepository.php'

    class FacebookRepository
{
    protected $facebook;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->facebook = new Facebook([
            'app_id' => config('providers.facebook.app_id'),
            'app_secret'    => config('providers.facebook.app_secret'),
            'default_graph_version' =>  'v11.0'
        ]);
    }

        public function redirectTo()
    {
    $helper = $this->facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    $permissions = [
        'pages_manage_posts',
        'pages_read_engagement'
    ];

    $redirectUri = config('app.url') . '/home/facebookPage';

    return $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectUri, $permissions);
    }

      public function handleCallback()
{
    $helper = $this->facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();


    if (request('state')) {
        $helper->getPersistentDataHandler()->set('state', request('state'));
    }

    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
        throw new Exception("Graph returned an error: {$e->getMessage()}");
    } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
        throw new Exception("Facebook SDK returned an error: {$e->getMessage()}");
    }
    //$accessToken = Api::where('app_id', 107003655273452)->pluck('access_token')->first();
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    if (!isset($accessToken)) {


        throw new Exception('Access token error');
    }

    if (!$accessToken->isLongLived()) {
        try {
            $oAuth2Client = $this->facebook->getOAuth2Client();
            $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
        } catch (FacebookSDKException $e) {
            throw new Exception("Error getting a long-lived access token: {$e->getMessage()}");
        }
    }

    return $accessToken->getValue();

}

    public function getPages($accessToken)
{
    $pages = $this->facebook->get('/me/accounts', $accessToken);
    $pages = $pages->getGraphEdge()->asArray();


    return array_map(function ($item) {
        return [
            'access_token' => $item['access_token'],
            'id' => $item['id'],
            'name' => $item['name'],
            'image' => "https://graph.facebook.com/{$item['id']}/picture?type=large"
        ];
    }, $pages);
}
```

'Controller\SocialController.php'

```
class SocialController extends Controller
```

{
protected $facebook;

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->facebook = new FacebookRepository();
}

    public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return redirect($this->facebook->redirectTo());
}

    public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    if (request('error') == 'access_denied')
    {
        //handle error
        dd(request('error'));
    }

    $accessToken = $this->facebook->handleCallback();
    //dd($accessToken);

    //use token to get facebook pages
    $page = $this->facebook->getPages($accessToken);


     //store acceess token in databese and use it to get pages

    //dd($accessToken);


    return redirect(route('facebook.login.callback'))->with('page', $page);
```

}

Comment: Please dont post text as images

Comment: That's normal. You can only use the code that comes back from the authentication flow once. You need to store the token (in the browser, or in your database) if you want to use it on subsequent requests.